# iPhone app crashes when I change "Main Interface"

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I have a navigation based iPhone app, and I want to load a view (MainMenu.xib) when the app is launched, instead of MainWindow.xib. If I change the target's "Main Interface", the app crashes when it is launched. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the view you want to display on MainWindow.xib......in the IB of  MainWindow.xib you have to change the name of the class as well as the nib name (give the name of the class)

After doing this make the object of the view in the Application delegate

In navigation based you also  need to give the name of the class you  want to display(this class is the class in which you had designed your table view)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean view based. I meant Navigation Based. I understand, but what do I do when I want to display the table view?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it turned out I really should have been using view based. I copied my files over to a v. based app, and it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

adding this comment a few years after the problem first posted as can cause problems if you have Storyboards to manually change MAIN INTERFACE instead of choosing from drop down. If value in field is not a .storyboard file then xocde changes the plist setting to NIB based project and breaks the whole project.

See my comment here

[What does "Main Interface" in Xcode actually *do*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420768/what-does-main-interface-in-xcode-actually-do/20498650#20498650)