# What does "Main Interface" in Xcode actually *do*?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm moving some older projects to Xcode 4.5, and I'm a bit baffled as to the actual function of the Main Interface project dropdown.  What does the framework actually do with that value?

Comment: If you aren't using storyboards, it lets you specify a default XIB & view controller to use. Generally speaking storyboards are the way to go, however.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's where you can specify what Interface Builder file (xib) you want to load on launch, if you're not using a Storyboard.

Comment: Awesome! You can copy-paste my comment above.

Comment: Except your answer was posted well over a minute after mine, and says exactly the same thing as my comment, which took me 15 seconds to write.

Comment: And that proves what? Couldn't I have opened the site before you posted your comment?

Comment: Also, if you set the root view controller manually you don't need to choose a storyboard here

Answer (score 1):

beware if you have a storyboard based project. 
Editing the MAIN INTERFACE field manually is dangerous.
If storyboard is not found it thinks you mean a NIB.
will change the app to a NIB based project. 
Safer to choose a storyboard from the drop  down.

```
BEFORE - i has a storyboard based project
UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad : Main_iPad
UIMainStoryboardFile      : Main_iPhone
```

I mistype the name in MAIN INTERFACE field to Main_iPhone1
I ran the app and it crashed as Main_iPhone1.storyboard doesnt exist
I changed it back to Main_iPhone but project refused to build even after a lot of cleaning.

Casued by the key in the plist also changing along with the value

```
AFTER
UIMainStoryboardFile : Main_iPad
NSMainNibFile          : Main_iPhone1  <<project changes to NIB based
```

Changing Main_iPhone1 back to Main_iPhone
only changed it from Main_iPhone1.xib to Main_iPhone.xib which doesnt exist and also crashes.